# How to delete all merged code changes from a specific git branch

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch, git-merge

I have a feature branch which was repeatedly merged in our develop branch for testing. But I need to merge that develop branch into our master branch without the code changes of the specific branch. Has anyone have an idea how to do it??

Basically I want to remove all merges from the feature branch into the develop branch. And I have no better idea except for cherry picking.

I really don't want to cherry pick because that branch was merged over 50 times into our developer trunk...

Comment: Well, you always can create a release branch from master, in which you merge all features you want to have and merge it back into master. This assumes that you don't directly commit on the development branch.

Comment: We are 5 code monkeys without controll... ofc we commited directly :).   the problem is, we dont push our local branches so i have no way to to tell what is my and what is theirs. i only have one branch wich i need to delete.

Comment: I fear you won't be able to get around cherry picking, unless you want to change the history of the development branch, which you would need to `push --force`. But this is a big "No! No!" when working with a team on a repo. But maybe someone else has a better idea, although I doubt it.

Comment: There is no other way. I question what the purpose of the feature branch is, however, if you repeatedly merge it into the main development branch. The typical case is the other way around, keeping the feature branch updated by repeatedly merging into it, that way you can still kill off the feature, or postpone it, without having remnants of it already merged into the main development branch. This is usually the main reason for having the feature branch in the first place, which is why I question why you are doing it that way.

Comment: Yes tht was the plan, and usual proces... but our menager dous not get the concept untill now. so she forced me to merge the unfinished feature into develop, and now she is telling me to "remove it"... tht should not be so hard... sihg QQ